# How to convert JSON object to JSON array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I would like to convert this JSON object

```
{"target":{"Start":"2017-08-01","End":"2017-09-01"},"datapoints":[{"UsageQuantity":{"Amount":"6","Unit":"Hrs"}}]}
{"target":{"Start":"2017-09-01","End":"2017-09-01"},"datapoints":[{"UsageQuantity":{"Amount":"8","Unit":"Hrs"}}]}
```

to a JSON Array in the following way, taking only the start date

```
[{"target": "Yearly", "datapoints": [[6, 2017-08-01], [8, 2017-09-01]]}]
```

Comment: they will tell you that there's no such thing as JSON object nor JSON array, and to show us what you have tried.

Comment: Where does `Yearly` come from? Also, there are 2 objects there. Are they already within an array? How are they declared?

Comment: As stated by @yBrodsky, please post the code you have already tried.

Comment: @Intervalia I am new to NodeJS and was trying to figure a way on how to do this. I have not really coded this.

Comment: @user184994 I want to declare a variable "yearly". And for the other comment, yes the 2 objects are already within an array. These objects are retrieved from AWS API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the cleanest code and it does not take into account that `datapoints` might have more then one entry, but it gives the data format you are looking for.

```js
var origin = [
  {
    "target": {"Start":"2017-08-01","End":"2017-09-01"},
    "datapoints":[
      {
        "UsageQuantity": {"Amount":"6","Unit":"Hrs"}
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "target":{ "Start":"2017-09-01","End":"2017-09-01"},
    "datapoints":[
      {
        "UsageQuantity":{"Amount":"8","Unit":"Hrs"}
      }
    ]
  }
]

var output = {
  target: "Yearly",
  datapoints: origin.map((item) => [item.datapoints[0].UsageQuantity.Amount, item.target.Start])
}

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try assigning the objects to an array variable then stringify the array variable. Something like:

```
var createArray = [var1, var2, var3];
var yourArray = JSON.stringify(createArray);
console.log(yourArray);
```

I believe `yourArray` is what you want